# Unity3D WebGL doesn´t show the game

Tags: web, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have tried several forums without any results. I am pretty desperate, so I made a game and built it in WebGL, then I tried to run it locally (on both firefox and chrome) and also put it on a website specially developed for unity web gl games and in both cases it showed only loading with Unity logo and after that nothing happened. The screen stayed the same color as the splash screen. I tried it on different computers with the same results, I tried to change many options in the Chrome and I also made a completely new plain project and it's always the same. Thank you very much for any help.
This is the screenshot how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKDgK.jpg
The game itself: http://www.sharemygame.com/share/a2937ca1-2827-4595-b939-28d02d7cc6b8

Comment: You need to look in the browser developer console for errors. `Invalid serialized file version. File: "globalgamemanagers". Expected version: 5.6.3f1. Actual version: 5.6.3p2.`  It would appear you haven't rebuilt the game and any asset bundles with the same version of Unity.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for your reply, so I opened the index file in google and it didnt show anthing, in developer console it says : "Failed to load file:///D:/Work/UnityFiles/"MyGameBuild/Build/Build.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." I will try to open it on Firefox

Comment: @RetiredNinja Actually maybe I know what it can be about when you mentioned the versions. Because today I was installing the WebGl plugin to Unity and my unity version is 5.6.3p2 and when I tried to download the WebGl I went to Unity downloads and chose 5.6 and it probably downloaded f1 version. Any tips how can I make it work, how should I repair the version difference then

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yep, I downloaded the right version and it works perfectly. Thank you very very much for your help.